# connection pooling in clustered environment

Tags: tomcat, connection-pooling

How connection pool are managed in clustered environment.
This question is regarding :-
Setting up clustered using tomcat,spring-hibernate web application.

For one tomcat instance i am getting connection through JNDI from tomcat defined in context.xml.I have two Questions if i deploy the same in clustered.

First: Do we have connection pool for each Node ?(for each instance of tomcat)
Second: And if it is one connection pool for all nodes.then how will do it.Do we create connection pool in one server?

Please clarify connection pooling in clustered environment.I did google but did not concrete answer.Actually I have set up the tomcat cluster with 3 nodes ,session replication and fault tolerance is working fine - so need to know about connection pool.

or rather simple: what would be best approach if we set up connection pool in production environment.

Comment: Your question is not clear.. Which language (Java/.Net) you are talking about?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I have just edited my question.Kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

Answering late. May be helpful to someone.
Connection pool is for every server in clustered environment. The connections per node or server will be less as request is divided among cluster servers. Connections cannot be shared among nodes/servers.